# MKMapView mathod 'didUpdateUserLocation' not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have this code in my file,

```
@synthesize myLocation;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    myLocation.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [myLocation setShowsUserLocation: YES];

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.myLocation setRegion:[self.myLocation regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

But, method didUpdateUserLocation not calling.

I already added required frameworks in app.

I added everything in info.plist file. But still it is not calling.

This is my .h file,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapView : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myLocation;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

Comment: Did you add the delegate? (CLLocationManagerDelegate) Please post your class instantiation too.

Comment: And where is the `MKMapView` object? Where is set its delegate?

Comment: Added everything in question. @Larme

Comment: use `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

Comment: Check my answer brother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the problem,

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    myLocation.delegate = self;
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [myLocation setShowsUserLocation: YES];
```

Use **setShowUserLocation** with value **YES** after **startUpdatingLocation**

Answer (score 1):

You have not called the method to update the location yet so the delegate method is not getting called. You need to call method for `startUpdatingLocation`.

```
For Objective - C:

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

For Swift:

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother I tried your code.The delegate method is not called.

Then I found out the solution you did not add below line at the end of the viewDidLoad method. Please add

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

After I added above line code in viewDidLoad method,the delegate method called successfully.